# Zeo server log output with multiple zeo clients

Tags: plone, zope

We use a zeo server and three zeo clients.
Zope version is 2.13.19

It works fine but I want to understand why some of the following connections are connected and unconnected.

Ultimately, only three connections show received handshakes which accounts for the three clients.

```
2018-03-30T16:23:24 (23621) terminated by SIGTERM
2018-03-30T16:23:24 (23621) closing storage '1'
2018-03-30T16:23:24 (127.0.0.1:51272) disconnected
2018-03-30T16:23:24 (23621) removed PID file '/home/magikzope/var/zeo.pid'
2018-03-30T16:23:25 (9915) created PID file '/home/magikzope/var/zeo.pid'
2018-03-30T16:23:25 (9915) opening storage '1' using FileStorage
2018-03-30T16:23:25 StorageServer created RW with storages: 1:RW:/home/magikzope/var/filestorage/Data.fs
2018-03-30T16:23:25 (9915) listening on ('127.0.0.1', 9100)
2018-03-30T16:23:27 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 45414): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 45414)>
2018-03-30T16:23:27 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 45416): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 45416)>
2018-03-30T16:23:27 (127.0.0.1:45416) received handshake 'Z3101'
2018-03-30T16:23:27 (127.0.0.1:45414) received handshake 'Z3101'
2018-03-30T16:23:27 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 45418): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 45418)>
2018-03-30T16:23:27 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 45420): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 45420)>
2018-03-30T16:23:27 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 45422): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 45422)>
2018-03-30T16:23:27 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 45424): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 45424)>
2018-03-30T16:23:27 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 45426): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 45426)>
2018-03-30T16:23:27 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 45428): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 45428)>
2018-03-30T16:23:27 (127.0.0.1:45426) received handshake 'Z3101'
2018-03-30T16:23:27 (unconnected) disconnected
2018-03-30T16:23:27 (unconnected) disconnected
2018-03-30T16:23:27 (unconnected) disconnected
2018-03-30T16:23:27 (unconnected) disconnected
2018-03-30T16:23:27 (unconnected) disconnected
2018-03-30T16:23:27 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 45430): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 45430)>
2018-03-30T16:23:27 (unconnected) disconnected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SIGTERM` hints that the threshold for an allowed max-RAM was suceeded, like it can happen on a virtual-server, in that case you'll want to upgrade your hosting-plan, to have more RAM available.

In case you did reboot your OS, or were the reason for the `SIGTERM` in another way yourself, this can also happen and the reasons may be various, one can be the cache-validation, as described in the source-code of `ZEO-5.1.1-py2.7.egg/ZEO/cache.py` at line 64:

```
# When the client is connected to the server, it receives
# invalidations every time an object is modified.  When the client is
# disconnected then reconnects, it must perform cache verification to make
# sure its cached data is synchronized with the storage's current state.
```

So in general it's nothing to have sorrows about, the clients try to connect and disconnect until a valid connection is established.

However it is always a good idea to start instances in a staging- or development-enviroment in foreground, before changing anything in production.

Comment: Terminated by SIGTERM is shown because I restarted the server

Comment: :-) That explains the source of the signal. With server you mean the operating-system, I suppose and that restart means you were rebooting it.

Comment: Sorry.. I mean the Zeo Server and Zeo Clients and not the OS. But sometimes, it takes ages i.e., plenty of connects and disconnects 3-4 mins before the Client-ZEO connection is established

Comment: Hm using the `plonectrl`-script for shutting down or restarting instances doesn't trigger a `SIGTERM`-signal. I'm afraid you have to live with the ages, as written it's likely but not certainly that cache-validations are a cause of the many retries.

Comment: Huh, got 500 points for guessing a reason, that feels illegitimate. Good example for the relativity of this measurement (similar to IQ-points).